# Finding Election Precincts from Latitude-Longitude Coordinates

Tags: geocoding

I have a list of latitude-longitude coordinates (and addresses if that helps). I want to find which voting precintcs they are located in. Is there any easy way to do this in R? Here is a sample of my data:

[image]